# Self-hosted cross-platform push notification service

Tags: windows, android, linux, osx, ios

I work at a remotely located research camp in the Arctic. We have a couple of dozen people working here, connected by WiFi and with satellite-based internet.

For emergencies or general calls it would be nice to have a one-way communications system for the administration that does *not* rely on the internet. I'm thinking this could be done with a set of mobile (iOS/Android) and desktop (Win/Mac/Linux) apps that would subscribe to some message queue and push e.g. a Growl notification in the case of a general call.

I could build it myself with a Redis queue and a lot of effort to write five apps. But there must be a better way! Also, I don't know if it's even possible to wake an iOS device without the APN service.

Would any of you have any recommendations for me? Thanks, much appreciated.